# How to Natigate from react activity to java activity

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I am using *react-native* bridge to create my own native module but I need to navigate in an other native activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, VideoStreamingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("videoTitle", "Hello World");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

but my application is stopping